# Audio position in SpeakProgress event is not correct for "Microsoft Anna" voice

Tags: c#, text-to-speech

In a text to speech application by c# I use SpeechSynthesizer class, it has an event named SpeakProgress which is fired for every spoken word. But for some voices including "Microsoft Anna" the parameter `e.AudioPosition` is not synchronized with the output audio stream, and the audio stream is played faster than what AuidoPosition indicates.

```
void reader_SpeakProgress(object sender, SpeakProgressEventArgs e)
{
      Console.Write(e.AudioPosition + "");
}
```

I thought maybe the problem is the bitrate and the WaveStream as the output which I use as the following.

```
  FileStream AudioStream 
    = new FileStream(fname, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write); 
   reader.SetOutputToWaveStream(AudioStream);
```

I tried

```
var formats = CurVoice.VoiceInfo.SupportedAudioFormats;
reader.SetOutputToAudioStream(AudioStream, formats[0]);
```

But the problem now is that the output file is not played.
Do you have any suggestions for why the voice is not synch and why my solution has no 
playable output audio?

Comment: Works for me, it speaks presumably?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have guessed the problem was related to bitrate, to enforce the audio format I used an alternative method named `SetOutputToWaveFile`

```
var formats = CurVoice.VoiceInfo.SupportedAudioFormats;
reader.SetOutputToWaveFile(fname, formats[0]);
```

with the code above, the audio output is playable and also the synching problem resolved!